# Set theme Holo.Light in Mono for Android

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, mono

Im new to this android development, and im currently playing around with the `HelloM4A` project that follows the Mono for Android installation.

I have also noticed that Google wants us to use their design gudide, and I found a theme in that guide that they use. It is called `Holo Light`.

Now, how do I append that theme to my project? Do I need to download the theme, or is it standard on the phone?

I tried this code (below) but it did throw an build error, strange enough since I did not find the error in my `Error list`.

```
[Activity(Label = "HelloM4A", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/Theme.Holo.Light")]
public class Activity1 : Activity
{
    int count = 1;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

        button.Click += delegate { button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++); };
    }
}
```

This is my project layout:

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In u project there is something name manifest file .
u have to give the theme got the activity as shon below.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.aviz.pep.android.ui.classname"
       android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
```

instead of theme.transulent.notilebar
add your theme name but make sure you are using the latest sdk

Comment: Thanks, but as you see from my project layout (in my post) I do not have a manifest file. Should I create it? Where should it be? Rememeber im using Visual Studio and Mono for Android.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I also found this link that might help. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/holo-everywhere.html